# does world size affect performance?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Surprisingly I couldn't find any meaty info about this, so here I am.

I understand that 1 unit in the editor = 1 meter, but does large worlds affect performance? I mean, they obviously do in sandbox games and other games packed with content. But what if it's mostly empty? My current project is a 2D Gravity Wars clone game with moving planets. Should I make it as small and condensed as possible, or is there room to scale things up?

*Basically, do large distances in a mostly empty world affect in-game performance?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer ... No.

The only thing you lose with big numbers when we are talking about float based vectors is precision.

So the real question becomes ... how accurate do you want your logic to be?

I tend to build stuff placing verts on round value points then scale for size rather than space vertex info at scaled points ... if that makes sense / helps?

Comment: It does makes sense (most of it), thanks! Is there any rule of thumb as to how big a float vector can be before precision becomes a problem? Do you know of any good resources for reading up on that last paragraph you wrote?

Comment: There are a lot of resources on this sort of thing ... sadly though I don't have any to hand, and if i'm honest I don't fully understand it myself but what I do understand is that its to do with the 32 bits you have for float values, if you use them to show a big number more bits can be used for the bit after the decimal, if you have a large number then less of those bits are free for precision. Most math these days only really uses / wants for our purposes about 5 to 10 decimal places so you can get some huge numbers before a problem.